# assert celery task runs or not runs

Tags: python, django, celery

I am working on a django project as an
Intern, I am developing the project not coding it from start, I added a feature to
contact us section, the feature is about
sending support's answer to user who sent the contact message via email after the support answered the message in admin panel, I start celery task for sending email in post_save receiver function based on some conditions, I would like to unit test this feature, what is matter to
me is does celery receives task in some conditions or it doesn't I need something like this assertCeleryRecievesTask(task_name) or not, for now it is not important if the task itself works as expected just wanna know if the task starts or not, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the celery signals.
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/signals.html